# How to extract complete sub links using Simple-HTML-DOM?

Tags: php, hyperlink, anchor, simple-html-dom

The following is the basic code I use to extract sublinks from a page:

```
<?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    function extract_links($target_url)
    {   
        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html->load_file($target_url);  
        $i=0;
        $crawl =array();
        foreach($html->find('a') as $link)
        {
            $crawl[$i] = $link->href;
            $i++;
        }
        var_dump($crawl);
    }
    extract_links('http://stackoverflow.com');
?>
```

The output is as follows:

```
array
  0 => string 'http://stackexchange.com' (length=24)
  1 => string '/users/login' (length=12)
  2 => string 'http://careers.stackoverflow.com' (length=32)
  3 => string 'http://chat.stackoverflow.com' (length=29)
  4 => string 'http://meta.stackoverflow.com' (length=29)
  5 => string '/about' (length=6)
  6 => string '/faq' (length=4)
  7 => string '/' (length=1)
  8 => string '/questions' (length=10)
  9 => string '/tags' (length=5)
  10 => string '/users' (length=6)
  11 => string '/badges' (length=7)
  12 => string '/unanswered' (length=11)
  13 => string '/questions/ask' (length=14)
  14 => string '?tab=interesting' (length=16)
  15 => string '?tab=featured' (length=13)
  16 => string '?tab=hot' (length=8)
  17 => string '?tab=week' (length=9)
  18 => string '?tab=month' (length=10)
  19 => string '/questions/14611052/basic-standalone-jpa-example-with-postgres-using-eclipse' (length=76)
  20 => string '/questions/tagged/eclipse' (length=25)
  21 => string '/questions/tagged/postgresql' (length=28)
  22 => string '/questions/tagged/jpa' (length=21)
  23 => string '/questions/14611052/basic-standalone-jpa-example-with-postgres-using-eclipse' (length=76)
  24 => string '/users/865448/tostao' (length=20)
  25 => string '/questions/14611172/unable-to-fully-print-a-page-containing-iframes-in-chrome' (length=77)
  26 => string '/questions/tagged/javascript' (length=28)
  27 => string '/questions/tagged/jquery' (length=24)
  28 => string '/questions/tagged/html' (length=22)
  29 => string '/questions/tagged/html5' (length=23)
  30 => string '/questions/tagged/google-chrome' (length=31)
  31 => string '/questions/14611172/unable-to-fully-print-a-page-containing-iframes-in-chrome' (length=77)
  32 => string '/users/962868/tejas' (length=19)
  33 => string '/questions/14609779/how-can-i-configure-bash-to-handle-crlf-shell-scripts' (length=73)
  34 => string '/questions/tagged/linux' (length=23)
  35 => string '/questions/tagged/windows' (length=25)
  36 => string '/questions/tagged/bash' (length=22)
  37 => string '/questions/tagged/line-endings' (length=30)
  38 => string '/questions/14609779/how-can-i-configure-bash-to-handle-crlf-shell-scripts/?lastactivity' (length=87)
  39 => string '/users/1899640/that-other-guy' (length=29)
  40 => string '/questions/14611169/using-one-socket-for-peer-to-peer-communication' (length=67)
  41 => string '/questions/tagged/sockets' (length=25)
  42 => string '/questions/tagged/p2p' (length=21)
  43 => string '/questions/14611169/using-one-socket-for-peer-to-peer-communication' (length=67)
  44 => string '/users/911651/xsnrg' (length=19)
  45 => string '/questions/14611166/possible-mistake-in-ios-dev-guide' (length=53)
  46 => string '/questions/tagged/iphone' (length=24)
  47 => string '/questions/tagged/ios' (length=21)
  48 => string '/questions/tagged/objective-c' (length=29)
  49 => string '/questions/14611166/possible-mistake-in-ios-dev-guide' (length=53)
  50 => string '/users/107715/matt-n' (length=20)
  51 => string '/questions/14611163/how-to-use-dispatcher-in-wpf-to-make-a-timer' (length=64)
  52 => string '/questions/tagged/wpf' (length=21)
  53 => string '/questions/tagged/timer' (length=23)
  54 => string '/questions/tagged/dispatcher' (length=28)
  55 => string '/questions/14611163/how-to-use-dispatcher-in-wpf-to-make-a-timer' (length=64)
  56 => string '/users/1741800/nashat' (length=21)
  57 => string '/questions/14610879/how-can-i-handle-an-access-violation-in-visual-studio-c' (length=75)
  58 => string '/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b' (length=32)
  59 => string '/questions/tagged/exception-handling' (length=36)
  60 => string '/questions/tagged/access-violation' (length=34)
  61 => string '/questions/tagged/structured-exception' (length=38)
  62 => string '/questions/14610879/how-can-i-handle-an-access-violation-in-visual-studio-c/?lastactivity' (length=89)
  63 => string '/users/901812/big-endian' (length=24)
  64 => string '/questions/14611162/mvc-condintional-authorization' (length=50)
  65 => string '/questions/tagged/c%23' (length=22)
  66 => string '/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc' (length=29)
  67 => string '/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4' (length=31)
  68 => string '/questions/tagged/authorization' (length=31)
  69 => string '/questions/14611162/mvc-condintional-authorization' (length=50)
  70 => string '/users/644969/cadrell0' (length=22)
  71 => string '/questions/14611160/get-customer-role-nopcommerce' (length=49)
  72 => string '/questions/tagged/c%23' (length=22)
  73 => string '/questions/tagged/razor' (length=23)
  74 => string '/questions/tagged/nopcommerce' (length=29)
  75 => string '/questions/14611160/get-customer-role-nopcommerce' (length=49)
  76 => string '/users/1378841/mlg74' (length=20)
  77 => string '/questions/14611158/iframe-resizing-nested-in-gridview' (length=54)
  78 => string '/questions/tagged/resize' (length=24)
  79 => string '/questions/14611158/iframe-resizing-nested-in-gridview' (length=54)
  80 => string '/users/2026451/satish-patil' (length=27)
  81 => string '/questions/14611157/php-how-to-check-the-value-got-this-word-from-a-var' (length=71)
  82 => string '/questions/tagged/php' (length=21)
  83 => string '/questions/tagged/preg-match' (length=28)
  84 => string '/questions/tagged/strpos' (length=24)
  85 => string '/questions/14611157/php-how-to-check-the-value-got-this-word-from-a-var' (length=71)
  86 => string '/users/963414/samual99' (length=22)
  87 => string '/questions/14611155/how-to-get-the-coordinates-of-boundries-of-drawable-on-the-mapview' (length=86)
  88 => string '/questions/tagged/android' (length=25)
  89 => string '/questions/tagged/google-maps' (length=29)
  90 => string '/questions/14611155/how-to-get-the-coordinates-of-boundries-of-drawable-on-the-mapview' (length=86)
  91 => string '/users/1520564/blubar' (length=21)
  92 => string '/questions/14611153/why-css-is-empty-when-ssl-is-on-and-appcache-is-enabled-ipad-safari' (length=87)
  93 => string '/questions/tagged/css' (length=21)
  94 => string '/questions/tagged/ipad' (length=22)
  95 => string '/questions/tagged/ssl' (length=21)
  96 => string '/questions/tagged/mobile-safari' (length=31)
  97 => string '/questions/tagged/html5-appcache' (length=32)
  98 => string '/questions/14611153/why-css-is-empty-when-ssl-is-on-and-appcache-is-enabled-ipad-safari' (length=87)
  99 => string '/users/2026375/twoface' (length=22)
  100 => string '/questions/14611149/laravel-how-to-temporarily-store-eloquent-models-in-db-without-a-proper-schem' (length=97)
  101 => string '/questions/tagged/php' (length=21)
  102 => string '/questions/tagged/laravel' (length=25)
  103 => string '/questions/14611149/laravel-how-to-temporarily-store-eloquent-models-in-db-without-a-proper-schem' (length=97)
  104 => string '/users/291557/duality' (length=21)
  105 => string '/questions/13928812/xmlserializer-generateserializer-and-collections' (length=68)
  106 => string '/questions/tagged/c%23' (length=22)
  107 => string '/questions/tagged/xml-serialization' (length=35)
  108 => string '/questions/13928812/xmlserializer-generateserializer-and-collections/?lastactivity' (length=82)
  109 => string '/users/1200614/phil' (length=19)
  110 => string '/questions/14611145/keep-buttons-in-view-when-keyboard-opens-android' (length=68)
  111 => string '/questions/tagged/android' (length=25)
  112 => string '/questions/tagged/keyboard' (length=26)
  113 => string '/questions/tagged/resize' (length=24)
  114 => string '/questions/tagged/window' (length=24)
  115 => string '/questions/tagged/views' (length=23)
  116 => string '/questions/14611145/keep-buttons-in-view-when-keyboard-opens-android' (length=68)
  117 => string '/users/1137413/725623452362' (length=27)
  118 => string '/questions/14611144/ssdp-discovery-from-a-browser' (length=49)
  119 => string '/questions/tagged/silverlight' (length=29)
  120 => string '/questions/tagged/flash' (length=23)
  121 => string '/questions/14611144/ssdp-discovery-from-a-browser' (length=49)
  122 => string '/users/191882/legege' (length=20)
  123 => string '/questions/14611143/how-to-syncrhonize-on-site-in-memory-no-sql-datasources-with-central-database-in' (length=100)
  124 => string '/questions/tagged/architecture' (length=30)
  125 => string '/questions/tagged/nosql' (length=23)
  126 => string '/questions/tagged/java-ee-6' (length=27)
  127 => string '/questions/tagged/in-memory-database' (length=36)
  more elements...
```

Now consider '**/about**' sublink in the array. I want it to be displayed as '**https://stackoverflow.com/about**'. Why only subpart of sublink is returned while in some cases complete sublink is returned ?
Also some links are starting with '**?**' sign. How to sanitize these links ?

**EDIT:**
Consider "**`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler`**". Now if I perform extract_links on it, I get a sublink like this "**`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler/wiki/Web_search_engine`**" which is invalid and most of the links are of this format. The correct link is "**`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_search_engine`**". **And I am using this function in another program which will pass an array of links so I cannot keep the if conditions *static***. The following is the code fragment I am using now:

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $link)
{   
    $href = $link->href;
    $fchr = substr($href, 0, 1);
    if ($fchr === '/')
    {
        $href = $target_url.$href;
    }
    else if ($fchr === '?')
    {
        $href = $target_url.'/'. $href;
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful about HTML-scraping StackOverflow. See [Etiquette of Screen-scraping Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/446/132449). Consider using the [API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage) instead if you can.

Comment: There are [several options available](http://scraperblog.blogspot.com/2012/12/convert-relative-urls-to-absolute-in.html) for converting relative urls to absolute. Choose one of these.

Comment: @ithcy Thanks for the heads up. I am not scraping it by the way. Just did that to show an example.

Comment: @pguardiario Please check the edited part of the question.

Comment: Check it for what? You should be using a library for this. Your code won't work, it's not even close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *@pguardiario's comment*

As suggested in his comment `phpUri` is the perfect solution for converting relative URLs to absolute. You can find it [here,](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/phpuri)

Answer (score 1):

Any link starting with "/" is an absolute path from the doc root.  To get the complete URL you would need to prepend the hostname in which that link was found.  For relative links, such as the "?tab=etc", you will need to prepend the complete URL in which the link was found.  If you want to ignore the query string links ("?tab=etc") use a regular expression to do so.

Comment: Yea I am prepending as you said. But check the edited part of the question. How to handle such sublinks ?

Answer (score 1):

In html source, definition of this `a` element is `<a href="/about">about</a>`, thus it returned existing href value as `/about`.

If you want to display links with http and domain try this (all internal links could start with `/` or `?`);

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $link) {
    $href = $link->href;
    $fchr = substr($href, 0, 1);
    if ($fchr === '/') {
        $href = 'http://stackoverflow.com'. $href;
    } else if ($fchr === '?') {
        $href = 'http://stackoverflow.com/'. $href;
    }
    $crawl[] = $href;
}
```

PN: You don't need `$i` while pushing non-assoc arrays, just `$array[] = ..` is ok.

**UPDATE**

Assuming you have trouble with "internal links" (so, these are may not contain http or site url). And actually I don't know how to detect internal links anymore. I think this grabs all those: `'foo', '/foo', '?foo', '#foo', '../foo', '/../foo'`. But suppose these seems not valid?? `'../foo', '/../foo'`.

```
// or more strong pattern
if (!preg_match('~^((ht|f)tp?s*)://.*~i', trim($href))) {
    $href = 'http://www.site.com/'. ltrim($href, '/');
}
```

Comment: Okay this will work nicely for a single link. Check the edited part of the question. Using this will create an issue in case of particular link as mentioned in the edited part of the question.

Comment: The problem is much more complicated than this. Consider all of: 'foo', '/foo', '?foo', '#foo', '../foo', '/../foo'