# Output complete link in each href

Tags: php, curl, hyperlink, simple-html-dom

Im using Curl with simple html dom to scrape a website and in order to fix relative links I insert a base tag like this:

```
foreach($html->find('head') as $f) {
    $f->innertext = "<base href='$url'>" . $f->innertext;
}
```

Where `$url` is the website Im scraping. The problem is that the links are physically outputted like this:

```
<a href="/path_to_file"> link </a>
```

While I need the full url in the link like so:

```
<a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/path_to_file"> link </a>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I Fixed the URL's using the anwser provided over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611721/how-to-extract-complete-sub-links-using-simple-html-dom

Answer (score 0):

append the url each time you are setting it.

```
$base_url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/";
foreach($html->find('head') as $f) {
    $f->innertext = "<base href='$base_url$url'>" . $f->innertext;
}
```

Comment: `Where $url is the website Im scraping` from your question

Comment: you haven't shown us how `$url` is populated so its assumed that you are setting it somewhere

Comment: What I called `$url` you then called `$base_url` So now I have two variables...?

Comment: yes you do have two variables. i appended `$base_url` to the href. `$url` remains intact. you can do the same thing this way 

`$f->innertext = "<base href='".$base_url.$url."'>" . $f->innertext;`

Comment: Youre not getting it...The website Im scraping is ONE varaiable, which you for some reason called `$base_url` I called it `$url` So in conclusion: `$base_url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/";` and my own code `$url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/";` Do you see how the variable value is the SAME THING. How does this help me: `http://www.somewebsite.com/http://www.somewebsite.com/`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47551/discussion-between-anurupr-and-youss)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the base URL like this:

```
<?php 
    $baseURL =  "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
?>
```

then prepend `$baseURL` to your href

Comment: This may return also "index.php" so it won't be suitable.

Comment: Like @Filip Górny said it return the complete url: index.php?url=and_so_on